# making an array of n columns where each successive row increases by one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy, I would like to be able to input n for rows and m for columns and end with the array that looks like:

```
[(0,0,0,0),
 (1,1,1,1),
 (2,2,2,2)]
```

So that would be a 3x4. Each column is just a copy of the previous one and the row increases by one each time. As an example:
input would be 4, then 6 and the output would be and array

```
[(0,0,0,0,0,0),
 (1,1,1,1,1,1),
 (2,2,2,2,2,2),
 (3,3,3,3,3,3)]
```

4 rows and 6 columns where the row increases by one each time. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you mean 3 in the last row of your second array right?

Comment: What are you going to do with this array?  You might be able to avoid creating such an array if the subsequent operations can use numpy's broadcasting ability.

Answer (score 5):

So many possibilities...

```
In [51]: n = 4

In [52]: m = 6

In [53]: np.tile(np.arange(n), (m, 1)).T
Out[53]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [54]: np.repeat(np.arange(n).reshape(-1,1), m, axis=1)
Out[54]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [55]: np.outer(np.arange(n), np.ones(m, dtype=int))
Out[55]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Here's one more.  The neat trick here is that the values are not duplicated--only memory for the single sequence [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1] is allocated.

```
In [67]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [68]: seq = np.arange(n)

In [69]: rep = as_strided(seq, shape=(n,m), strides=(seq.strides[0],0))

In [70]: rep
Out[70]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Be careful with the `as_strided` function.  If you don't get the arguments right, you can crash Python.

To see that `seq` has not been copied, change `seq` in place, and then check `rep`:

```
In [71]: seq[1] = 99

In [72]: rep
Out[72]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3]])
```

Comment: Slick. I hadn't noticed that you already showed how to use `as_strided`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def foo(n, m):
    return np.array([np.arange(n)] * m).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Natively (no Python `list`s):

```
rows, columns = 4, 6
numpy.arange(rows).reshape(-1, 1).repeat(columns, axis=1)
#>>> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#>>>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#>>>        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
#>>>        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using built in python functions. The program counts to 3 converting each number to a string and repeats the string 6 times.

```
print [6*str(n) for n in range(0,4)]
```

Here is the output.

```
ks-MacBook-Pro:~ kyle$ pbpaste | python
['000000', '111111', '222222', '333333']
```

Comment: user2785334 asked for a matrix of *numbers*, not characters. Furthermore, user2785334 wants to do it with a Numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

On more for fun

```
np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.int) + np.arange(n, dtype=np.int)[:,None]
```

Comment: Slight variation: `(np.zeros((m,n), dtype=int) + np.arange(n)).T`

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, there are many ways to do this.
Here's what I'd do:

```
import numpy as np
def makearray(m, n):
    A = np.empty((m,n))
    A.T[:] = np.arange(m)
    return A
```

Here's an amusing alternative that will work if you aren't going to be changing the contents of the array.
It should save some memory.
Be careful though because this doesn't allocate a full array, it will have multiple entries pointing to the same memory address.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
def makearray(m, n):
    A = np.arange(m)
    return as_strided(A, strides=(A.strides[0],0), shape=(m,n))
```

In either case, as I have written them, a `3x4` array can be created by `makearray(3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `count` from the built-in module `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> rows = 4
>>> columns = 6
>>> cnt = count()
>>> [[cnt.next()]*columns for i in range(rows)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply

```
>>> nc=5
>>> nr=4
>>> [[k]*nc for k in range(nr)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Several other possibilities using a (n,1) array

```
a = np.arange(n)[:,None]  (or np.arange(n).reshape(-1,1))

a*np.ones((m),dtype=int)

a[:,np.zeros((m),dtype=int)]
```

If used with a (m,) array, just leave it (n,1), and let broadcasting expand it for you.